# Typescript + Vue reactive exported variable

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-dataflow

### Setup

I have a Vue3 + Firebase project.
In its `main.ts` i am exporting an object called `userInfo` like this:

`export var userInfo :any = {}`

> Don't mind the `:any`, it is to fix Typescripts `*some-property* does note exist on type Object`.

This object is set by a hook, also inside `main.ts` that runs when a user is authenticated as follows:

```
auth.onAuthStateChanged(async () => {
    if(!auth.currentUser) return

    userInfo = await getUserInfo()
})
```

Now of course, the object is only filled when the `onAuthStateChanged` hook fires, which is after imports are handled in my .vue files.

### Problem

When importing my ´userInfo´ in some .vue file with `import {userInfo} from '@/main'`
the file of course imports the still empty object.
Sometime after the `onAuthStateChanged` hook fires and fills the object.

The component however does not refresh the import, meaning  i do not have the data that i need inside my .vue file.

### Question

I would like the gathering of my userInfo centralized and then just import it into my .vue components instead of manually gathering it everytime i need to use it.

**How do i work around this problem of the object being filled after imports are handled?**

Comment: You should use Vuex to set the user info when it is fetched. Later on you can get it from Vuex anywhere you need it. Check it out: https://v3.vuex.vuejs.org/

Comment: Also, don't use any as it defeats the whole purpose of typescript. Define an interface for userInfo and declare it as such.

Comment: Not much information here but sounds like a limit of your target module format. System JS modules actually transpile the semantics of live bindings as per the esm spec.

Comment: userInfo cannot be reactive when you reassign it. It should be a ref or reactive const, see https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/state-management.html#simple-state-management-with-reactivity-api

Comment: consider trying https://vueuse.org/firebase/useAuth/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other comments and answers are suggesting to use a store and it should be what you are searching for in your project. As you are using Vue3 and Typescript, I would recommend using [**Pinia**](https://pinia.vuejs.org/introduction.html) which is the current up to date store manager for recent Vue applications and not [VueX](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) which is the older store manager.

You can find really good examples in the documentation. I personally used Pinia [in a similar fashion in a personal project](https://github.com/s-rigaud/huskyfy/blob/main/src/stores/user.ts), maybe this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a mutation using vuex. So all child children and parent parents can interact from anywhere
example : https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/07/14/vue-vuex-user-registration-and-login-tutorial-example

Moreover :

```js
export async function getAuthUserID(): Promise<string | undefined> {
  return await new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
    firebase.auth().onIdTokenChanged(async (user) => {
      if (!user) {
        resolve(undefined);
      } else {
        resolve(user.uid);
      }
})
  }).then((uid: string | undefined)=>uid).catch(function(e) {
    throw (e);
  });
}
```

Comment: Sorry, your code snippet throws an error?

Comment: this is `javascript` code.
your code `typescript` code. You can write using `TypeScript` syntax. The important thing here is that the function is async.